# Запись в базу данных ms sql с помощью Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

У меня есть три связанных таблицы с описанными сущностями:

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public City CapitalId { get; set; }
    public float CountryArea { get; set; }
    public decimal Population { get; set; }
    public Region RegionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Capital { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Region> Region { get; set; }

}

public class Region

{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }

}
public class City
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

Вот таким образом я записываю информацию в бд

```
using (var context = new LocalDbContext())

            {


                {
                    foreach (CountryInfo countryInfo in countryList)
                    {
                        

                        context.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = countryInfo.Name, 
                                CountryCode = countryInfo.NumericCode, CountryArea = 
                                countryInfo.Area, Population = countryInfo.Population, });
                        context.Regions.Add(new Region() { RegionName = countryInfo.Region });
                        context.Cities.Add(new City() { CityName = countryInfo.Capital  });
                        
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
```

Но при этом я не понимаю, как мне в столбцы "RegionId" "CapitalID" таблицы  "Country" записать информацию из соответствующих таблиц

Comment: у вас EntityFramework или EntityFrameworkCore ?

Comment: [Связь один ко многим (EF)](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.7.php)

Comment: [Отношение один ко многим (EF Core)](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.5.php)

Answer (score 0):

Как пример

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public float CountryArea { get; set; }
    public decimal Population { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Region> Region { get; set; }

}

public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public int CountryID{get; set;}//foreing key
    public Country Country { get; set;}
}
```

В EF Core существует понятие Lazy load(ленивая загрузка).
Например:

```
var country = new Country {Name = "aaa", CountryCode = "bbb", CountryArea = 0, Population = 0};

var region = new Region {RegionName = "ccc"};
var regions = new List<Region>();
regions.Add(region);
country.Region = regions;

//При добавлении Country добавится и связанные сущности regions
_db.Countries.Add(country);

_db.SaveChanges();
```